# Search string in database (column) and get corresponding row values (google sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, stock

I'm making a data entry form on google sheets. I've made a search bar for it. Writing the symbol name should return the qty, buy, target and sl. The problem is that it does not return anything if I enter the symbol name in the box and click on search.

It accepts only integer, if I search for "1" or "2", it is returning the symbol. However, that is of no use for me. I need to search by the symbol name.

Here's the code. Cannot seem to fix it after searching alot. Thanks for the help!

```
var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 0;
function Search() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Entry"); //Form Sheet

  var str = formS.getRange("H7").getValue();
  var values = ss.getSheetByName("MV").getDataRange().getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {
      formS.getRange("H11").setValue(row[0]),
      formS.getRange("H13").setValue(row[1]),
      formS.getRange("H15").setValue(row[2]),
      formS.getRange("H17").setValue(row[3]),
      formS.getRange("H19").setValue(row[4]);
      formS.getRange("H19").setValue(row[5]);
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

The above box is sheet "Entry" and the data is in "MV".

BEL is in cell D4.

Search box is H7

Comment: The name is at index 3 of values and your only search on index 0

Comment: If you want to search on name then SEARCH_COL_IDX = 3

Comment: It might be worth modifying the user interface to provide a way to select which column or columns to search on.   Of course selecting multiple columns will require a considerably more complex change in the code.